# Is there a UX design app like Adobe XD for iPad?

Tags: ipad-app

Is there any app like Adobe XD which is specifically designed for making prototypes of app interfaces, rather than simply for freehand drawing, for iPad?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details – and at least point out your core requirements (must-haves), and the price margin. Thanks!

Comment: Just leave another comment when done, so I can check to reopen your question. Thanks!